decomposition of the symmetric product of SU(3) adjoint representation
Consider the adjoint representation of $SU(3)$, which is an 8-dimensional representation. The symmetric product $\operatorname{symm}^2\mathbf{8}$ can be decomposed into
$$
\operatorname{symm}^2\mathbf{8} = \mathbf{1} \oplus \mathbf{8} \oplus R_{2 \theta}
$$
where $R_{2\theta}$ is the 27-dimensional representation with highest weight $2\theta$.
I want to see this decomposition at the level of explicit generators. For example, the symmetric product $J^{(a} J^{b)}$ can be rewritten as (here parenthesis $(a b)$ in the indices denotes the symmetrization)
$$
J^{(a} J^{b)} = (J^{(a} J^{b)} - \frac{1}{8}K^{ab}K_{cd}J^{(c} J^{d)}) + \frac{1}{8}K^{ab}K_{cd}J^{(c} J^{d)}  \ ,
$$
corresponding to the extraction of $\mathbf{1}$. But how to extract the ${R}_{2\theta}$ piece? I tried to incorporate the cubic Casimir into the game, but wasn't successful.

I guess the $1$ corresponds to the Killing form while the $8$ corresponds to $(A, B) \mapsto i(AB + BA)$? That means the third term is the orthogonal complement of these two, although that probably isn't very satisfying.

@QiaochuYuan Right the Killing form corresponds to $\mathbf{1}$, and I tend to think (not sure) that the $\mathbf{8}$ corresponds to the combination $d^{a}{{bc}}J^bJ^c$ with the cubic Casimir $d$. But I am not able to put everything into a nice decomposition $J^a J^b = ...$, where the $\mathbf{1}, \mathbf{8}$ and $R{2\theta}$ parts are isolated explicitly.

Perhaps this is only a partial answer, but in your case, the quadratic Casimir operator will act on those 3 representations with different eigenvalues. For $R_{2\theta}$, that eigenvalue should be 8 and the eigenvalue on ${\bf 8}$ should be 6. The Lemma and Corollary here is relevant (you can ignore the first theorem):
https://concretenonsense.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/kostants-theorem-on-the-ideals-defining-homogeneous-spaces/
Although the corollary is about tensor products of irreducible representations, you can embed the symmetric square into ${\bf 8} \otimes {\bf 8}$ so there is no problem.
